# Why i get an Http 503 Error by query a API

Tags: java, api, http

I wrote an Java Program that query a API from haveibeenpwned.com. And nearly every time i get the output:

```
run:
Fehler
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 503
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

That's looks like an DDOS Protection but in my Browser all works fine so i don't can explain that and i don't find any other errors.

My Code:

```
package checkpassword;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class CheckPassword
{

    //Thats an old Email from Me ^^
    final static String testMail = "cool-man25@web.de";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

//        ArrayList<String> mailList = createEmailList();
//        
//        for(int i=0; i<mailList.size(); i++)
//        {
            System.out.println(getOutput(testMail));
//        }

    }



    public static String getOutput( String Mail )
    {

        String output;

        try
        {

            URL url = new URL("https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/breachedaccount/" + Mail);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            output = br.readLine();

            conn.disconnect();

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output = "Fehler";
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static ArrayList createEmailList()
    {

        ArrayList<String> mailList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/s.kobe/Desktop/test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while(true)
        {
            String Zeile = br.readLine();
            if(Zeile != null)
            {
                mailList.add(Zeile);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }

        br.close();

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    return mailList;    
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Sandro

//Some text that i reach the requirements to ask my Question because i think that i explain all important stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP 503](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) means that the service is temporarily unavailable.

However, since you say it works just fine in a browser, it is likely that the web server is configured to respond this way to scripts such as yours.

You could try spoofing the [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string, which means you could pretend to be a modern web browser, and see if the server responds differently. You might want to look into [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/), which will let you try this out quickly on the command line.